# IE11 vertical flex-box layout with height:auto and overflow doesn't work

Tags: html, css, flexbox, internet-explorer-11

I have two vertical boxes, both have `height: auto` and the second one needs to scroll if the content is over the max-height defined by the parent.

```css
.wrapper {
  position: fixed;
}

.popup {
  position: fixed;
  width: 200px;
  max-height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.a {
  left: 0
}

.b {
  left: 200px;
}

.header {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  border: 2px solid green;
}

.body {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="popup a">
    <div class="header">
      first popup
    </div>
    <div class="body">
      "Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas
      sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora
      incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea
      voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?"
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="popup b">
    <div class="header">
      second <br> popup
    </div>
    <div class="body">
      "Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis istiam, eaqcabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Everything works great except in IE11 where the container in overflow doesn't scroll.

Any way i can have this exact behaviour on IE11 as well as modern browsers?

PS: there would be a solution if i was able to have a defined height for the header?

Comment: I should really get into it to give you a definite answer, but flexbox in IE is full of bugs. Refer to [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) for a list

Comment: @giorgio i know but believe me it's not really my choice to support it

Answer (score 1):

### Flex items in IE11 ignore `max-height` and `min-height` on containers.

Your flex container (`.popup`) is set to `max-height: 300px`.

The flex items (`header` and `body`) couldn't care less. They ignore that height command.

For an illustration of this behavior use `height: 300px` instead. Now it works.

**Solution #1**: If you can use `height` instead of `max-height`, your problem is resolved. ([demo](https://jsfiddle.net/qx0bzcL3/))

Also, while this problem applies to flex containers, it doesn't apply to flex items. `min-height` and `max-height` are respected on flex items in IE11.

Therefore, you can make `.wrapper` a flex container, which makes the `.popup` flex containers into flex items, as well. Now `max-height` works as intended.

This would be enough to solve the problem if the `.popup` elements were not using fixed positioning. Flex items set to `position: fixed` are removed from the normal flow, which includes removal from flex layout. So the `.popup` items are no longer flex items.

**Solution #2:** If you can work without fixed positioning on the `.popup` elements, then make the parent a flex container, and you may be all set. ([demo](https://jsfiddle.net/qx0bzcL3/2/))

---

References:

- [IE11 `min-height` bug report](https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs#flexbug-3) (seems to also apply to `max-height`)
- ["As it is out-of-flow, an absolutely-positioned child of a flex container does not participate in flex layout."](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#abspos-items)

Comment: As you can see the `.popup` element has `max-height` set.

Comment: Yes but just saying i'm playing by the rules, is IE11 that is not.

Comment: Consider i might actually be able to have an height for the header, still not sure how that could help using only css

Comment: https://jsbin.com/megafel/17/edit made both containers position: absolute and made wrapper a flex container. Issue is not fixed

Comment: `position: flxed` and `position: absolute` are the same thing, just with different reference points. `position: fixed` is a form of absolutely positioning. `.popup` ignores flex properties if `fixed` or `absolute`. Must be in-flow.

Comment: Well yes with a relative positioning there would be no problem i know, but it's really part of the layout and i cannot do without it.

Comment: I posted two solutions. If you can't use solution #2, then use solution #1. You'll need to give something up for this layout to work in IE11. (Much of the criticism of IE11 is well-deserved.)

Comment: I know, sadly i can't. For now i had to use a javascript solution that would be totally out of the scope of this question. Good to know that at least i did not get stuck on a trivial issue.